GCP Classic Application LB returns 'upgrade_header_rejected' on socket.io GET request
There is a NestJS application wrapped in Docker container. It has socket.io endpoint for clients configured like this:
@WebSocketGateway({
  transport: ['websocket'],
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
    credentials: true,
  },
  allowUpgrades: true,
  pingInterval: 25000,
  pingTimeout: 20000,
})
export class SocketGateway implements OnGatewayConnection { ... }

The app deployed in GCP as Cloud Run (v2) service with pulumi. Using direct Cloud Run URL I can reach my socket endpoint and set up connection between my client (I use Postman to play around with it) and deployed service: https://<cloudrunv2service.url>/socket.io
Then I tried to configure my own Load Balancer with HTTPS certificate still usign pulumi. Everything works well except socket gateway. It returns Bad Request 400. Using Logs Explorer I figured out some details:
"jsonPayload": {
  "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.loadbalancing.type.LoadBalancerLogEntry"
  "backendTargetProjectNumber": "projects/77577xxxxxxx"
  "remoteIp": "x.x.x.x" 
  "statusDetails": "upgrade_header_rejected"
}

Can't beat this issue. I do not understand what am I doing wrong and how I can tell to Load Balancer do not reject Upgrade header. Actually this is completely insane.
Here is my pulumi code I used to deploy and configure load balalncer:
const backend = new gcp.compute.BackendService(`${name}-backend`, {
  name: `${name}-backend`,
  portName: 'http',
  protocol: 'HTTPS',
  sessionAffinity: 'CLIENT_IP',
  loadBalancingScheme: 'EXTERNAL',
  backends: [{ group: regionNEG.id }],
  connectionDrainingTimeoutSec: 60,
  enableCdn: false,
  customRequestHeaders: ['Connection: Upgrade', 'Upgrade: websocket'],
});

const urlMap = new gcp.compute.URLMap(`${name}-url-map`, {
    defaultService: backend.id,
    hostRules: [{ hosts: [args.domain], pathMatcher: 'allpaths' }],
    pathMatchers: [
      {
        name: 'allpaths',
        defaultService: notFoundBackend.id,
        pathRules: [
          ...
          {
            paths: ['/api', '/api/*'],
            service: backend.id,
            routeAction: {
              urlRewrite: { pathPrefixRewrite: '/' },
            },
          },
          {
            paths: ['/*'],
            service: notFoundBackend.id,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }
);

const proxy = new gcp.compute.TargetHttpsProxy(`${name}-proxy`, {
  urlMap: urlMap.id,
  sslCertificates: [cert.id],
});

const address = new gcp.compute.GlobalAddress(`${name}-address`, {});

const forwardingRule = new gcp.compute.GlobalForwardingRule(
  `${name}-forwarding-rule`,
  {
    target: proxy.id,
    portRange: '443',
    ipAddress: address.address,
  },
);

Little note: I use path rewriter to remove /api from request path when it comes to LB. Then request comes to my Cloud Run service.
Please, give me some ideas or tell me what am I doing absolutely wrong so my websocket endpoint doesn't work. How can I configure GCP LB to stop rejecting Upgrade header? Thank you.
